# Check if all object in array is greater than x number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of objects representing sales data for different cities. Each city has an array of rooms with corresponding counts. I want to check if all cities have a count of at least three for rooms 2, 3, and 4. If this condition is met, I would like to obtain the names of all the cities that satisfy it.

Here is an example of the data structure:

```
const sales = {
  "City 1": [
    {
      "rooms": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "rooms": 2,
      "count": 2
    },
    {
      "rooms": 3,
      "count": 3
    }
  ],
  "City 2": [
    {
      "rooms": 1,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "rooms": 2,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "rooms": 3,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "rooms": 4,
      "count": 2
    }
  ],
  "City 3": [
    {
      "rooms": 2,
      "count": 6
    },
    {
      "rooms": 4,
      "count": 7
    }
  ],
  "City 4": [
    {
      "rooms": 1,
      "count": 4
    },
    {
      "rooms": 2,
      "count": 6
    },
    {
      "rooms": 3,
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "rooms": 4,
      "count": 7
    }
  ]
};
```

Several solutions I tried

```
for (const city in sales) {
    let isPass = true;
    for (const room of sales[city]) {
      if (room.count < x) {
        isPass = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isPass) {
      // do stuff here
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Also tried

```
let filteredCities = [];

  for (const city in sales) {
    const roomsData = sales[city];

    const hasRoom2 = roomsData.some((room) => room.rooms === 2);
    const hasRoom3 = roomsData.some((room) => room.rooms === 3);
    const hasRoom4 = roomsData.some((room) => room.rooms === 4);

    const isCount = roomsData.every(
      (room) => room.count >= 3
    );

    if (hasRoom2 && hasRoom3 && hasRoom4 && isCount) {
      filteredCities.push(city);
    }
  }

  return filteredCities;
```

I need assistance in writing a JavaScript function that will perform this check and return the following:

A boolean value indicates whether all cities have at least three counts for rooms 2, 3, and 4.
If the boolean value is true, a list of the names of the cities that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Please add your attempts to your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.

Comment: Please add whatever you tried

Comment: your expected result shouldn't even return `city 3` as the only object who meets the requirement because you said `if all the counts in all the cities are more than 3"` that means that `city 3` also don't meet that criteria because `room 3` has 3 as the `count` value so therefore is not more than `3` and your function shouldn't return anything

Comment: What isn't clear about your question so far: **1:** Do you mean that *every city* must pass the check? Or do you want to check *each city independently*? **2:** "a count of at least three for rooms 2, 3, and 4" – Do you need to check if *total sum* of their counts is >= 3, or *each count*  is >=3?

Comment: @blakkwater 1. I want to check each city independently and select the one that passes the test, 2. each count is >=3 in rooms 2, 3, and 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it cleaner to separate out the code that finds the rooms by id from the main code.  I think it makes for more readable blocks.

Also, it wasn't clear to me what output you wanted.  So my version splits out finding the object entries that match your criteria from the formatting of their results.  If you wanted the output to look like the input object, just filtered to keep those that match your criteria, I would use this:

```js
const findRoom = (city, roomNbr) =>
  city.find(({rooms}) =>  rooms == roomNbr)

const findMatchingCities = (cities) => Object.entries(cities).filter (
  ([name, city]) => [2, 3, 4].every(roomNbr => findRoom(city, roomNbr)?.count >= 3)
)

const selectCities = (cities) => 
  Object.fromEntries(findMatchingCities(cities))

const sales = {"City 1": [{rooms: 1, count: 1}, {rooms: 2, count: 2}, {rooms: 3, count: 3}], "City 2": [{rooms: 1, count: 1}, {rooms: 2, count: 1}, {rooms: 3, count: 1}, {rooms: 4, count: 2}], "City 3": [{rooms: 2, count: 6}, {rooms: 4, count: 7}], "City 4": [{rooms: 1, count: 4}, {rooms: 2, count: 6}, {rooms: 3, count: 3}, {rooms: 4, count: 7}]}

console .log (selectCities(sales))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But if you just wanted the matching ciy *names*, I would use this function instead:

```js
const selectCityNames = (cities) => 
  findMatchingCities(cities).map(([name]) => name)
```

You can see it by expanding the following snippet:

```js
const findRoom = (city, roomNbr) =>
  city.find(({rooms}) =>  rooms == roomNbr)

const findMatchingCities = (cities) => Object.entries(cities).filter (
  ([name, city]) => [2, 3, 4].every(roomNbr => findRoom(city, roomNbr)?.count >= 3)
)

const selectCityNames = (cities) => 
  findMatchingCities(cities).map(([name]) => name)

const sales = {"City 1": [{rooms: 1, count: 1}, {rooms: 2, count: 2}, {rooms: 3, count: 3}], "City 2": [{rooms: 1, count: 1}, {rooms: 2, count: 1}, {rooms: 3, count: 1}, {rooms: 4, count: 2}], "City 3": [{rooms: 2, count: 6}, {rooms: 4, count: 7}], "City 4": [{rooms: 1, count: 4}, {rooms: 2, count: 6}, {rooms: 3, count: 3}, {rooms: 4, count: 7}]}

console .log (selectCityNames(sales))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In either case, the main function, `findMatchingCities` filters the entries of our input object, using our `findRoom` for each of the room numbers we want to test (`2`, `3`, `4`), and checking if they have a `count` property of at least `2`.  It returns an array of object entries, each in the form `['CityName', [{rooms: 1, count: 1}, ...]]` You could easily fold this into `selectCities` or `selectCityNames` and remove one function.  Or not.  This breakdown is fairly clean.

If the room numbers and/or the minimum count should be dynamic, it's trivial to add parameters to `findMatchingCities` and the function that calls it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I want to check each city independently and select the one that passes the test.
> 2. Each count is >=3 in rooms 2, 3, and 4.

So when you're checking each city, you just need to keep track of records that meet the requirements. You can do this by using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) filled with relevant `rooms` numbers. As you loop through the records, for each record, check if `rooms` is both present in the set and satisfies the condition. If true, delete it from the set. When the set becomes empty, you are sure that the current city passed the test. Refill the set for each subsequent city and repeat.

```js
const sales = {
  "City 1": [
    { "rooms": 1, "count": 1 },
    { "rooms": 2, "count": 2 },
    { "rooms": 3, "count": 3 }
  ],
  "City 2": [
    { "rooms": 1, "count": 1 },
    { "rooms": 2, "count": 1 },
    { "rooms": 3, "count": 1 },
    { "rooms": 4, "count": 2 }
  ],
  "City 3": [
    { "rooms": 2, "count": 6 },
    { "rooms": 4, "count": 7 }
  ],
  "City 4": [
    { "rooms": 1, "count": 4 },
    { "rooms": 2, "count": 6 },
    { "rooms": 3, "count": 3 },
    { "rooms": 4, "count": 7 }
  ]
};

function filterLocations (locations, rooms, minCount) {

    let names = Object.keys(locations);
    let found = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

        let location = locations[names[i]];
        if (!Array.isArray(location)) {
            continue;
        }

        let set = new Set(rooms);
        for (let j = 0; j < location.length; j++) {
            let entry = location[j];
            if (set.has(entry?.rooms) && entry?.count >= minCount) {
                set.delete(entry?.rooms);
            }
            if (set.size == 0) {
                found.push(names[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}

console.log(filterLocations(sales, [2, 3, 4], 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution,

I was able to solve it by iterating over each city and checking if the count for rooms 2, 3, and 4 is >= 3 in each city

Here:

```js
const sales = {
  "City 1": [{
    rooms: 1,
    count: 1
  }, {
    rooms: 2,
    count: 2
  }, {
    rooms: 3,
    count: 3
  }],
  "City 2": [{
    rooms: 1,
    count: 1
  }, {
    rooms: 2,
    count: 1
  }, {
    rooms: 3,
    count: 1
  }, {
    rooms: 4,
    count: 2
  }],
  "City 3": [{
    rooms: 2,
    count: 6
  }, {
    rooms: 4,
    count: 7
  }],
  "City 4": [{
    rooms: 1,
    count: 4
  }, {
    rooms: 2,
    count: 6
  }, {
    rooms: 3,
    count: 3
  }, {
    rooms: 4,
    count: 7
  }]
};


function checkCity(cities) {
  const availableCities = [];

  for (const city in cities) {
    const rooms = cities[city];

    const room2 = rooms.find(room => room.rooms === 2);
    const room3 = rooms.find(room => room.rooms === 3);
    const room4 = rooms.find(room => room.rooms === 4);

    if (room2 && room3 && room4 && room2.count >= 3 && room3.count >= 3 && room4.count >= 3) {
      availableCities.push(city);
    }
  }

  return availableCities;
}

console.log(checkCity(sales));
```